# implementing websocket in old php html4 website

Tags: html, websocket, phpwebsocket

We are already having chat application in our old system which is html4. We need to convert chat application code into "web socket" code.

Does it require to convert all the application html4 code to html5.

Also we are uploading files in chat application. Is it possible in web sockets and is it feasible to do so for chat application?

I looked at the web sockets and socket.io examples. Does web socket implementation with socket.io will work on all browsers.

Comment: Hey! Did you got the solution of implementing websocket on HTML4